# Attempting to use computed property name in an interface definition results in ts(1170)

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm facing a compiler error from TypeScript and I'm not entirely sure how it could be fixed. I am aware that `Pick`, `Omit` and similar mechanics exist, and that I could use them instead. What I want to understand is what exactly causes the compilation error ts(1170) in the definition of the interface `INewType`.

The ultimate goal is to be able to write Mongoose and MongoDB queries which use $lookup and $project in a way that traps potential refactoring attempts where the body of the query has not been adjusted to match.

A code exhibit which exemplifies the problem is presented below:

```
function nameof<T>(key: keyof T): keyof T {
    return key;
}

interface ISubType {
    fieldA: string;
}

interface ISomeType {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    subType: ISubType;
}

// This works fine; the resulting object has two fields
// named after the field names from the other types
const newObject = {
    [nameof<ISomeType>('name')]: 'Foo',
    [nameof<ISubType>('fieldA')]: 'Bar'
}

// This results in ts(1170)
interface INewType {
    [nameof<ISomeType>('id')]: string;
}
```

Link to [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGAhgWwKZ2AHgCoB8AFANYYCeAXImedongJTW316IDeAUIr4gE4YoIfkloBuLgF8uXGGCgZ+wFBAyIAkgGUQAIzzkADuu59EwGBgA2AEwCC1AM5R+8gOaSZchUpVrNWnCYBsacPHwwNk4u7pJmqJjRrmAe4byOeiEY1NqZRhiesgD0RQwAFjCOiADucPwkVRZgBYhQZeqCGVawKYhwugBWGNCIZShVULXmlraOXCXI6Bg2iCjAivyt7dPWKwkYjfxBW+pwbUqt+XMQCM7IGNUA8oPDUIgAvGFmANr72DjaIIYLLEADk+1BjAAutRQQAxOBwUEAGjSiF+S3+uX0+TBFl2dkhMMQoIAQih+KDpLIbmBHHArBgAHRWOBuIjNJ4vaCMSTzUp4CpVTogbpVeStRxEACM0oA7AAGRjeDZ+dQaAByDyyXz4GMwWMCwVxRFBkSJSVi0iAA).

EDIT #1: Fixed a missing parenthesis and double colon from the code example.

[@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz): `newObject`'s shape is `{ 'name': 'Foo', 'fieldA': 'Bar' }`. The bracket notation results in a computed property name, not an index signature. I've adjusted the question topic to better represent the intent. If required I can try adding a Mongoose schema definition and a query but that will bloat the question's code example.

Comment: ① Please make sure this is a [mre] without typos.  Consider testing it in an IDE. ② What is your intended type for `newObject`?  It is actually `{ [x: string]: string; fieldA: string; }` and has nothing about `name` or `ISomeType` in there.  You say it "works fine" but given what actually happens I'm not sure how to translate that into `INewType`.  You could just define it as `{ [x: string]: string }`, but I'm guessing that's not what you want.